Prove that the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_n - \sin(x_n)$ converges
I recently got into cobweb plots and was having some fun seeing the behavior of various recursive expressions. I tried $x_{n+1} = x_n - \sin(x_n)$ and found that depending on different values of $x_0$, the sequence converges to different values. Is there an analytical way to prove that this sequence always converges, and to what value it converges to depending on $x_0$?

I'm blanking on the name of the theorem, but if there is some $y$ such that $f(y) = y$, and $|f'(y)| < 1$, then the recursive formula $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ converges to $y$ for starting values near $y$. In this case $f(x) = x - sin(x)$.

Banach fixed-point theorem?

Graphically, it seems to converge to $2\pi\left[\frac x{2\pi}\right]$ where $[x]$ is the round function

@AdamRubinson That's it, thanks! In particular, I was thinking of the special case mentioned on the wiki page for fixed point iteration. The diagrams on that page are very helpful; iterating the function can be visualized as bouncing a line between the function and the line $y = x$. Here is such a diagram for this particular function, showing that the attracting fixed points are $2\pi n$, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

There are also fixed points / equilibria at $(2n+1)\pi$ but those are unstable.

First note that at each $x_0 = k \pi$ for an integer $k$ the iteration is constant so it converges to $k\pi$. Otherwise, if $m$ is an integer such that
$(2m - 1)\pi < x < (2m + 1)\pi$, one can rewrite the recursion as
$$x_{n + 1} - 2m\pi = x_n - 2m\pi - \sin(x_n - 2m\pi)$$
So it makes sense to let $y_n = x_n - 2m\pi$ and rewrite this as
$$y_{n+1} = y_n - \sin y_n$$
Here $-\pi < y_0 < \pi$ and $y_0 \neq 0$.
Using that $0 < \sin y < y$ for $y \in (0,\pi)$ and $y < \sin y < 0$ for $y \in (-\pi,0)$, one gets that the sequence
$\{y_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is monotone increasing and bounded above by $0$ if $y_0 < 0$, and is monotone decreasing and bounded below by $0$ if $y_0 > 0$. Thus the monotone sequence theorem says the sequence converges in either case to a limit $L \in (-\pi,\pi)$ satisfying $L = L - \sin L$. This implies that $\sin L = 0$ and therefore $L = 0$. Thus the limit of the $y_n$ is zero, which gives that the limit of the original sequence $x_n$ is $2\pi m$.
The above can be written succinctly as saying the limit is $2\pi [ {x_0 \over 2\pi}]$, where $[x]$ is the function taking $x$ to the nearest integer to $x$, unless $x_0$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$, in which case the limit is $x_0$.
